# How can I return a numberOfRowsInSection from Firebase Async

Tags: swift, firebase

Im retrieving counts from Firebase.children the data is async Im able to retrieve the count from a function callback but i cannot get the result out of the call back and return the rows. How can I complete this? Thank you in advance.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {   
    var number:Int!

    getFirData { (result) in

        number = Int(result.childrenCount)

    }

    return number   
}
```

This is the async data im retrieving from Firebase

```
func getFirData(completion:(result:FIRDataSnapshot)->()){

    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userAiD = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    dbRef.child("posts").queryOrderedByChild("userAiD").queryEqualToValue(userAiD).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        let snapshot = snapshot

        completion(result:snapshot )

    })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.  You'll have to fire off that query in `viewDidLoad()` or perhaps `viewWillAppear(_:)`, store the values of the query for reference in a property, and call `reloadData()` (or relevant insert methods) on your table view.

Comment: also just to add to you answer which took me a while to find out that the tableView must be added to the view controller in order to use reloadData()

Comment: Yes, you would need a reference to the `UITableView` instance in order to invoke any methods on it.  If you're subclassing a `UITableViewController` one is provided for you.